# Table cells shift on text show / hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

When you open a row with description (by clicking on a blue link), the cells in the table move sideward by a few pixels. It appears only when the table cell contains text, without text the table cells don't move.

[Here is an example of my problem.](http://jsbin.com/kutoq/1/edit) (I'm using Firefox)

HTML:

```
<table class="conferences-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="headers">
        <th colspan="4">Overall info</th>
        <th colspan="4">Arrangement style</th>
        <th colspan="3">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="room">
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="description-link">With Text</a></td>
        <td>81,4 m2</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>over the city</td>
        <td>90 pax</td>
        <td>50 pax</td>
        <td>30 pax</td>
        <td>34 pax</td>
        <td>90 EUR</td>
        <td>130 EUR</td>
        <td>15 EUR</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="description">
        <td colspan="11">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="room">
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="description-link">Without text</a></td>
        <td>81,4 m2</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>over the city</td>
        <td>90 pax</td>
        <td>50 pax</td>
        <td>30 pax</td>
        <td>34 pax</td>
        <td>90 EUR</td>
        <td>130 EUR</td>
        <td>15 EUR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="description">
      <td colspan="11">
          <div class="content">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
   width: 980px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
}
p {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.description-link').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.room').next('.description').find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To stop the vertical shift in Chrome, remove the margin on `.content p` and replace it with padding.
2. To stop the horizontal shift in Firefox use `table-layout: fixed;` to prevent the cells from adjusting their width.

[Have a jsBin!](http://jsbin.com/yuxug/1)

CSS

```
table { 
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px; /*Whatever desired number */
}
```

Consider using a [CSS Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to help avoid small problems like this in the future.

Comment: I've tried to remove all margins, but the issue still exists

Comment: Oh, haha it does in Firefox. One moment.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` is what you want. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it save much time!

Answer (score 0):

Please put your image tag in paragraph tag.

```
<p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt=""></p>
```

Comment: I did, but problem still actual

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `Paragraph tag` you used. Give a `Class` to that `<p>` tag with `margin-top:0px;`. that should work.

Comment: I've added a class with margin: 0; to paragraphs, but it no use

Answer (score 0):

Just fix a width for your td

```
     <style>
            td
            {
                width:300;
            }
     </style>
```

This should solve your problem.